# determine where python is running from in linux

Tags: python, linux, shell

I normally work in python on Windows and I use the dos command `where python` to make sure that I am using the virtual environments version of python.  What is the equivalent command in the linux shell?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are looking for command: `ps -aux | grep python`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `which python`.

- [which man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which)

---

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

---

```
C:\Users\anossovp>where python
c:\Python27\python.exe
```

Answer (score 4):

The thing you are usually looking for is not where Python itself is, but where it's libraries are. For that I would recommend this:

(from within the Python shell)

```
import sys
import pprint
pprint.pprint(sys.path)
```

Outside of that you can still do `which python` naturally.